# How do I save a generated xml file to Android external storage

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created a jquery form which has a script to generate an xml file. I want to save this generated file to an SD card on my Android tablet.

I just for the life of me can't figure out the script needed to save it.

I have this script on the .js used to create the XML

```
$('#ResultXml').val(newXml);
$('#SaveLink')
   .attr('href', 'data:text/xml;base64,' + btoa(newXml))
.attr('download', 'SiteVisit.xml');
$('#generated').show();
}
```

and a "SaveLink" button on my form that calls the script. This works on my desktop computer but does nothing on the android that the form is designed to deploy on.

I have added the permissions

```
 <preference name="android.permission"         value="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
 <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
```

to my config file (I am using PhoneGap Build)

Any help with this would be more than appreciated

Comment: Have you tried what's here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html ?
Generating the file in your Activity as a File instance and then saving it using what's taught in that link?

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out exactly what it says but I continue to try

Answer (score 0):

Using PhoneGap you can use the cordova plugin file:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

If you don't want to use phonegap, you can create an interface between your activity and your webview:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: I edited my question to how that I am already linking to the plugins but still get a blank page when I hit the SaveLink button. Is there some script I need to add to my SaveLink button?